# Splitting amount using comma in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, number-formatting

In oracle i need to split amount using comma such as 10,000 and 1,00,000 whatever it comes. I need to split this. Is there any solution available for this. Am stuck with this. my result set is comes as 1000 and 10000 etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **TO_CHAR** and desired number format.

```
SQL> with data(num) as(
  2  select 100 from dual union
  3  select 1000 from dual union
  4  select 10000 from dual union
  5  select 1000000 from dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT TO_CHAR(num, '9,999,999') FROM data;
```

Also, in **SQL*Plus** there is a default number format. You could set `numformat` as per your desired format:

```
SQL> set numformat 9,99,999
SQL> SELECT 100000 FROM DUAL;

   100000
---------
 1,00,000

TO_CHAR(NU
----------
       100
     1,000
    10,000
 1,000,000
```