# How to insert french number format in oracle SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing the issue to insert the french number in a number field of oracle.I am using SQL Developer IDE. When i  insert the number(say 3,4) its says invalid number. Specifically,

> I don't want to replace the value 3,4 to 3.4.

I tried with changing the **NLS Setting** also (using command

```
Alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=',';
```

If I use this command I am able to insert directly in editor but insert command is not working due to comma, Oracle assume that its another value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot insert number value with comma, instead use varchar data type

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam: never, ever store numbers in varchar columns. That is a really bad advice

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how you can insert number with comma in number data type?

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam: you can't and you don't need to.

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam What you see is not the way it is stored in database. The comma and dot are separators which are only for display purpose. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145216/splitting-amount-using-comma-in-oracle

Comment: Have you read in question: I don't want to replace the value 3,4 to 3.4

Comment: we can and we should insert the comma in number field if we are not working with UK or USA projects see the details.Its all about setting the NLS see the example https://community.oracle.com/thread/945042?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam So? You still didn't understand. A number is internally stored as variable size. Internally it is mantissa and exponent. The separator is only for **display** and not **stored** the way you see it.

Comment: @mcapatna You cannot store a separator in **NUMBER** data type. You are only talking about **display**.

Answer (score 4):

You can't and you don't need to.

The number format for SQL *literals* **requires** the `.` for the decimal separator.

In the column itself the decimal separator isn't stored at all. You just need to change the display format of the number. This is ideally done in your application, **not** on SQL level. But if you require this in the SQL output, use `to_char()` to format your numbers:

```
select to_char(your_number_column, '9999D99')
from your_table;
```

The `D` in the format mask will be replaced with the decimal separator defined by the current session's NLS settings.

A dot `.` and `,` are returned literally:

```
select to_char(your_number_column, '9999,99')
from your_table;
```

More details on the to_char() format mask can be found in the manual:
 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#BABIGFBA

Comment: Is there any setting that allows to skip `to_char` part and make it default `,`, but not `.`?

Answer (score 2):

You application/ide may be performing an implicit conversion of character data into number, which uses the session default nls_numeric_characters.
You can force the insert command to perform an explicit conversion as follows using to_number:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_language = ENGLISH;
Session altered
SQL> alter session set nls_numeric_characters = ',.';
Session altered
SQL> create table t1 (num_col number);
Table created
SQL> insert into t1 (num_col) values ('3.4');
insert into t1 (num_col) values ('3.4')
ORA-01722: invalid number
SQL> -- this is equivalent to:
SQL> insert into t1 (num_col) values (to_number('12345,678', '999999D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=.,'));
insert into t1 (num_col) values (to_number('12345,678', '999999D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=.,'))
ORA-01722: invalid number
SQL> -- now converting explictly
SQL> insert into t1 (num_col) values (to_number('12.345,678', '999999D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.'));
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into t1 (num_col) values (to_number('12345,678', '999999D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.'));
1 row inserted
```

in NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS the first character is the decimal separator and the second one is the thousands grouping marker.

The docs have more info:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2117.htm